# Json файл не обновляется после сериализации. Использую Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, сериализация

Вот код:

```
static string LoadGameData(string filename)
{
    TextAsset mytxtData = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(filename);
    return mytxtData.text;
}

public void update_achievement_json(string achievement_to_add)
{
    string achievement_str = LoadGameData("list_of_achievements");
    JObject jsonObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(achievement_str);
    jsonObj.Property(achievement_to_add).Value = true;
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
}
```

Ошибок нет, но файл не меняется.

Comment: а что из вашего кода меняет файл?

Comment: вот это `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);` возвращает строку, которую вы никуда не пишете.

Comment: вообще. он должен менять файл "list_of_achievements.json". Я на форумах смотрел, там так написано. Правда, в одном варианте было: var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);

Comment: фактически это список булевых значений. Скрипт должен находить одно из значений и менять его на true.

Comment: ну, помимо `LoadGameData` вам нужно написать метод `SaveGameData`, так как сейчас вы из файла только читаете, но ничего туда не пишете.

Comment: И в `SaveGameData` нужно передавать `var result`? Если да, то хоть примерно что там нужно написать? Хоть бы направления. Я понимаю, тут не принято задавать такие вопросы, но я, похоже, в тупике...

Comment: По идее да, передавать туда имя файла и результат, чтобы функция писала этот результат в файл. Пример не могу скинуть, с unity не работал никогда, но вроде [вот тут](https://forum.unity.com/threads/reading-and-writing-json-files-c-litjson-awfulmedia.351806/) что то есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теоретически так:

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);
    sw.Write(updated_jsonFile_str);
    sw.Close();
```

Но, видимо в Android нельзя менять Json файлы. Если кто знает как, поправьте. буду благодарен.